# Correct usage of GetComputerName - Do I need to reserve extra space for null character

Tags: c++

I was wondering, what is the correct usage of [GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Should it be

```
TCHAR computerName[1024 + 1];
DWORD size = 1024;
GetComputerName(computerName, &size);
```

or

```
TCHAR computerName[1024];
DWORD size = 1024;
GetComputerName(computerName, &size);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The size passed in the `lpnSize` parameter reflects the amount of space available in the buffer, including space for the null terminator. Either of your statements will work, because in the first one you're just allocating one more byte than what you're saying is available.

You may want to use `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH` instead, which is much less than 1024.

```
TCHAR computerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
DWORD size = sizeof(computerName) / sizeof(computerName[0]);
GetComputerName(computerName, &size);
```

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: The division is a common idiom that determines the number of elements in a statically allocated array, without explicit reference to the array size or type. Yes, you could say `DWORD size = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;` but that's just repeating yourself and is prone to error if you decide to change the size of the array later.

Comment: I think it's worth highlighting that the size of a TCHAR's can alter depending on the character set the code builds with. Unicode=2 bytes, MBCS=1byte. Which is why sizeof division idiom is used :)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says explicitly:

> The buffer size should be large enough
>   to contain MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1

And then:

> If the buffer is too small, the
>   function fails and GetLastError
>   returns ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW. The
>   lpnSize parameter specifies the size
>   of the buffer required, including the
>   terminating null character.

Which means that you either:

1. Create a buffer with length `MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1`
2. Create a smaller buffer, but then be sure to catch the error value in case it's too small. In this case note that *On input, [lpnSize] specifies the size of the buffer, in TCHARs.* so the second version is correct

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you may try:

```
CString value;
DWORD size = 1024;
if(!GetComputerName(value.GetBufferSetLength(size), &size)){
    value = _T("");
}
return value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`size` is the size of the buffer (on input), not the length of the string. On output it is the length of the string. Your second version is correct. The first one does not hurt, though. But please do consider using MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH instead of some hard-coded value.